# 3d matrix probability error in R

Tags: r, matrix

I have 3 matrix which is combined into a 3D matrix.i have to find the probability such that a value from hidden sequence 's' matches to one of the matrix values in P.Mainly i get an error in the last coding region of 'obssim'

```
P1=cbind(c(1,2,3,4),c(1,2,3,4),c(1,2,3,4),c(1,2,3,4))
P2=cbind(c(1,2,3,4),c(1,2,3,4),c(1,2,3,4),c(1,2,3,4))
P3=cbind(c(1,2,3,4),c(1,2,3,4),c(1,2,3,4),c(1,2,3,4))

P=array(c(P1,P2,P3),c(4,4,3))

hssim=function(n,lambda)
{
        r=dim(lambda)[1]
        states=1:r
        s=vector("numeric",n)
        pi.lam=equil(lambda)
        s[1]=sample(states,1,FALSE,pi.lam)
        for (t in 2:n) {
                s[t]=sample(states,1,FALSE,prob=lambda[s[t-1],])
        }
        s
}

lambda=rbind(c(1,2,3),c(4,5,5),c(6,7,8))
s=hssim(10000,lambda) #(gives a hidden sequence)
obssim=function(s,P)
{
        n=length(s)
        r=dim(P)[3]
        q=dim(P)[2]
    states=1:q
        obs=vector("numeric",n)
        for (t in 1:n) {
        obs[t]=sample(states,1,FALSE,prob=P[,s[t],])
        }
        obs
}
```

I got an error when trying to call 'obs' and couldn't solve succeed in solving it:

```
obs=obssim(s,P)

Error in sample(states, 1, FALSE, prob = P[, s[t],]) : 
  incorrect number of probabilities
```

Comment: What is the function `equil` in `hssim`? Is that from some package?

Comment: equil is a function for equilibrium probabilities:
equil=function(P){
        e=eigen(t(P))$vectors[,1]
        e/sum(e)
}

Comment: I see, but from which package? It is not part of basic R instalation.

Comment: I did not install any additional package.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is, that what you pass as parameter `prob` is a 4x3 matrix, while object `states`, from which you choose, is a vector of four elements.

```
> states
[1] 1 2 3 4
> P[,s[1],]
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    1    1
[2,]    2    2    2
[3,]    3    3    3
[4,]    4    4    4
```

The length of `prob` should be the same as length of `x` in function `sample`. I suppose, that taking first (or any, since they are the same) column of that matrix would suffice

```
# replace line starting with obs[t] <- ...
obs[t]=sample(states,1,FALSE,prob=P[,s[t],1])
```

Than, the code runs without error